# doctrine-mongodb field mapping

Tags: symfony6, doctrine-mongodb

i have a problem fetching data with doctrine-mongodb bundle. If i use the "protected" access modifier for the document's fields, the fetched objects are empty. Here is an example of the class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Document;

use App\Repository\FingerprintRepository;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

#[MongoDB\Document(collection: "fingerprint")]
class Fingerprint
{
    #[MongoDB\Id(strategy: "AUTO")]
    protected string $id;

    #[MongoDB\Field(type: 'string')]
    protected string $fingerprint;

   public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

   public function getFingerprint(): string
    {
        return $this->fingerprint;
    }

    public function setFingerprint($fingerprint): self
    {
        $this->fingerprint = $fingerprint;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But if i change the field's access modifier to "public" then the document is correctly hydrated. I'm using the following software:

- PHP 8.1
- Symfony 6.3
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.5.2
- doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 4.4.3